# What Hinduism verse is similar to the following Christianity verse?

Tags: history, other-religions

What verse is most similar to the following verse in Hinduism?

> Love your neighbor as yourself. **Mark 12:31**

Answer (score 14):

[Mahabharata Shanti Parva 167:9](https://blog.practicalsanskrit.com/2013/05/do-unto-others-golden-rule-of-humanity.html)

> तस्माद्धर्मप्रधानेन भवितव्यं यतात्मना ।
> तथा च सर्वभूतेषु वर्तितव्यं यथात्मनि ॥
>
> Hence, by self-control and by making dharma your main
> focus,  **treat others as you treat yourself**.

FYI, Mahabharat is a contemporary historical account (Itihasa) of events that happened in Bharat (present day India), composed in poetry form in 125,000 verses by Rishi Ved Vyas at beginning of Kali Yug 5000+ years ago in 3102 B.C

Comment: Wait, you're saying that the Mahabharat was written 5000 years ago? That not right, is it?

Comment: @bornfromanegg Why not? A [quick check](https://www.ancient.eu/Indus_Script/) shows that the Indus script is roughly that old.

Comment: Well that seems very old to me. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahabharata) and several other sources seem to suggest it was no earlier than 400-500BC. 3000BC would make it older than anything on [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_literature) (which also puts Mahabharata at around 300-400BCE.

Comment: @Shadur it also shows that the Indus script is completely undeciphered and it's not even known what language it represents. Every source I can find without a clear bias says it was mostly written after 400 BC. Note that this ties into Indigenous Aryan theories, which are very strongly motivated by current Indian politics  (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigenous_Aryans )

Comment: @bornfromanegg - that is correct. Kali Yuga's start date has been precisely been mentioned in scriptures to be Feb 3102 B.C. Ved Vyasa composed them as a contemporary (he himself is present in the Mahabharat) Itihasa (historical account). Wikipedia links are generally left-learning and the Indologists who date them do not have any Vedic training. This would be akin to far-right American conservatives dating the Jewish/Moses period.

Comment: @llama - it is surprising that you call those external Western sources as unbiased, while discounting those from the traditional Vedic calendars (Panchang) that are followed by almost a billion people even today. The Aryan Invasion Theory is a nonsense just like the Proto-Indo-European theory. And this is not motivated by Indian Politics - but the other way round. The current Indian politics is a symptom of the awakening of the people to the truth of the antiquity of our civilization.

Comment: @ram Why would Western sources be biased?

Comment: @ram if I believed the bible or torah, I would think the earth is 6,000 years old. If I believed in hinduism, I would think something else. Since I believe in neither, and archaeology and related fields can be independently verified through multiple methods, I believe what they say.

Comment: @bornfromanegg - why would Indian sources be biased ? Do you believe in the existence of Jesus, or Buddha, despite there being no archaeological evidence of either ? Do you believe in the existence of Hitler despite you not actually seeing him in person, and all you have are photographs (which we all know can be manipulated easily)? Seems to me that your 'belief' is nothing other than 'blind faith in scientists', yet you seem to deride others whose 'belief' is nothing other than 'blind faith in rishis'.

Comment: @bornfromanegg - Btw, I'm neither a Jesus denier nor a Holocaust denier. But I am staunchly pointing out the lack of a philosopical-truth difference between the two.

Comment: I actually haven’t stated any beliefs - I’ve merely questioned a statement you made. And this is Hinduism StackExchange, so I don’t wish to engage in an argument about faith. Although, I do have to say that my “belief” in the existence of Hitler is not based on faith, as you suggest. It’s based on evidence. _That’s_ the difference.

Comment: @ram Also, can I just say that I had no intention of questioning your faith. When I asked the question, I had no idea that’s what I was doing.

Comment: @bornfromanegg - I too am merely questioning a statement you made - Why would Indian sources be biased ? No, your belief in the existence of Hitler is based on faith - because you have not personally met him. All you have seen are photographs, and other people claiming to have met/suffered at his hands or people claiming to have met such people. This is no different from me seeing paintings of Jesus (a primitive form of photography), and other people claiming to have met people claiming to have met...^n to have met Jesus. There is no fundamental difference between these 2 types of 'evidence'.

Comment: @ram Do you believe that cigarettes cause cancer? I do. Lots of people do. Yet no-one has ever observed the _actual_ moment when that happens. That doesn’t mean there’s no evidence for it, because first hand evidence is not the only kind of evidence. I don’t need to meet Hitler to believe he existed, because there is so much other evidence that he did. Again, _that_ is the difference

Comment: @ram Also, what statement of mine are you questioning? I never said, “Why would Indian sources be biased?” _You_ said that. I asked why _Western_ sources would be biased, and it was a _question_, not a statement. Of course, the real question, that I should have asked, is why would _any_ sources be biased?

Comment: @ram Also, painting is not a primitive form of photography. Fact.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117120/discussion-between-bornfromanegg-and-ram).

Comment: @ram is right. I want to warn every of the Hindu here that the christian churchmen who wants to convert Indians, are trying to change dates, concepts and truths from SD. Wikipedia is being corrupted. I am sure of it because someone from Usa generically wants to push Nations to follow Abrahmic cults in order to make the populations obey to them. Such purpose serves christianity among these.@bornfromanegg read "Brainwashed Republic" also. please. If you wish to be a naastika, then don't defend Wiki-Abrahmic created by- Pedia please. Thank you. Rather check Shastras and ask to scholars in here.